# install intern of update dojo releases

Tags: dojo, intern

According to the document install steps, a week ago it works(install success). When I installed and used the same steps today, and run npm test, it displayed the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukOcH.png)
I think maybe is Dojo releases update(a day ago), cause something has changed.
Now how can I success to install the intern?
Whether the document install steps need to revise and update?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't post images of error messages. Add the error message as text instead. Not as a comment, but in your question.

Answer (score 0):

package.json

```
"dependencies": {    
"tslib": "~1.7.1" }
```

revise

```
"dependencies": {
"tslib": "~1.8.0" }
```

package-lock.json
  tslib": "~1.7.1" revise  1.8.0